# How to show third party applications last used time?

Tags: android

According to my requirement I want to show **list of installed apps** with last used time.

I am using **UsageStatsManager**,but it is working only for lollipop. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("app.package.name", 0);
String appFile = appInfo.sourceDir;
long installed = new File(appFile).lastModified();
```

Comment: Above code is working for Applications updated time,but  I want to know last used time of Application.